# O atributo ref de um elemento do documento xml schema

Tags: xml, xml-schema, xsd

Estou fazendo um gerador de arquivos xml xs, mas estou com uma dúvida se algumas partes devem ser preenchidas.

```
<xs:element name="identificacao">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="modelo"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="prestador">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="identificacao"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="solicitacao">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="prestador" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

O **modelo** tem que ser estar presente e não pode ser repetido.

Os elementos **prestador** e **solicitacao** devem ter o atributo **ref=** preenchido?

Por exemplo:

- 1 formulário para o name=modelo.
- 1 formulário para ref=identificacao.
- Quantos formulários quiser para ref=prestador.

É isso mesmo?

Comment: Jobson, para ajudar você (e quem mais for ler isso no futuro), é isso que você quer saber? Cada solicitação deve ter n prestadores. Cada prestador deve ter 1 identificação. Cada identificação deve ter 1 modelo.

Answer (score 2):

Seu XSD valida o seguinte XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solicitacao xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:/Users/PeerBr/Desktop/test.xsd">
    <prestador>
        <identificacao>
            <modelo/>
        </identificacao>
    </prestador>
    <prestador>
        <identificacao>
            <modelo/>
        </identificacao>
    </prestador>
</solicitacao>
```

Resumindo:

- Uma solicitação por arquivo
- Cada solicitação tem que ter no mínimo um prestador
- Cada prestador tem que ter uma única identificação
- Cada identificação tem que ter um único modelo.

Sim, o attributo `ref` você precisa nesse caso. Ele designa que você se refere a um `complex type` - desse jeito, você pode usar esse `complex type` em outra parte do seu XSD sem ter que escrever de novo. Se você não precisa aproveitá-lo, pode fazer o seguinte para evitar o ref:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="solicitacao">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="prestador" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="identificacao">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="modelo"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Os dois jeitos validam igualmente.